# How to receive form input from asp form before moving to another page?

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, forms

I want to receive an input from a form (asp (C#)) and use this information in another page. The form's action is to go to another place.

I tried using:

```
Session["UserNameLog"] = Request.Form["user"];
```

But it doesn't succeed to get the info before moving to the other page...

```
<form action="index.aspx"  class="formcontainer"  id="formcontainer" method="post" runat="server">

Session["UserNameLog"] = Request.Form["user"];
```

I have also tried to use:

```
if(Page.isPostBack)
```

but the page is not back because I'm moving to another page...

Please help...
Thanks!

Comment: Try disable the autopostback

Comment: If you don't want the page to go to another place... then don't make the form action to another place.

Comment: Can you post a piece of code from your page that has form tag?